# PHP - Using a variable condition in a do-while loop?

Tags: php, loops, do-while

I'm wanting to set the condition of a do-while loop with a variable.  Here's my code...

```
$ans_type = mt_rand(1, 2);
if ($ans_type == 1){
    $condition = '$work_b != $c';
    $symbol = '=';
    $final_note = '1';
} else {
    $condition = '$work_b == $c';
    $symbol = '&ne;';
    $final_note = '2';      
}

do{
    $a = mt_rand(-25, 25);
    $b = mt_rand(-25, 25);
    $c = mt_rand(-25, 25);
    $d = mt_rand(-25, 25);

    if($op_1 == '&ndash;'){
        $work_b = $b * -1;
    } else {
        $work_b = $b;
    }

    if($op_2 == '&ndash;'){
        $work_d = $d * -1;
    } else {
        $work_d = $d;
    }
} while ($a == 0 || $b == 0 || $c == 0 || $d == 0 || $condition);
```

Note the `$condition` variable that I want to put in the `while()` part of the loop.  This produces an infinite loop though.

So, is there a way to use variables as conditions in loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do can be better achieved by using normal variables:

```
if( blah ) {
    $conditionstate = false;
} else {
    $conditionstate = true;
}

...
} while( ... || ($work_b == $c) == $conditionstate );
```

If you have more varied conditions, maybe a restructure is in order. If there really is no way to restructure it, I'm hesitant to suggest it, because so many people misuse it to terrible consequences, but `eval` does what you're looking for and can be safe (if not fast) if used carefully. Needing to use it is usually a sign that your program has a bad structure though.

p.s. These types of random number generation problems are much better solved with code like this:

```
$a = mt_rand(-25, 24);
if( $a >= 0 ) {
    ++ $a;
}
// $a is -25 to 25, but never 0

$b = mt_rand(-25, 23);
if( $b >= min( $a, 0 ) ) {
    ++ $b;
}
if( $b >= max( $a, 0 ) ) {
    ++ $b;
}
// $b is -25 to 25, but never 0 or a
```

That can be made more elegant, but you get the idea. No need to loop at all, and guaranteed to halt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables as conditions, however the reason your code produces an infinite loop is because you are not changing `$condition` within your while loop. Therefore, if `$condition` evaluates to true once, it will keep evaluating to true (as it never changes in your code).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ans_type = mt_rand(1, 2);
if ($ans_type == 1){
    $condition = ($work_b != $c);
    $symbol = '=';
    $final_note = '1';
} else {
    $condition = ($work_b == $c);
    $symbol = '&ne;';
    $final_note = '2';      
}
```

You are passing $condition as a string. Just save the $condition variable as a boolean.